# Feature to help other devs with CV typos etc

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv, spelling

I just noticed someone had a typo on a CV. I wish there was a feature for other users to highlight things like this. Something similar to the 'flag' functionality would be neat.

#### Edit:

This is perhaps more than just spelling mistakes. Sometimes there are technology name changes etc which might impact some job searches. Sometimes people are throw in things like VS instead of visual studio, or use ambiguous terms like VSS. And I don't mind helping people with things like this on a casual basis.

Comment: So you basically want Rich B for the careers site...

Comment: Kinda, but not really honestly...

Answer (score 7):

I would think that someone would take the time to make sure their CV was error free. It is like spelling errors on a resume or job application. Take a few minutes and invest in your future.

On the flip side, I like your idea for those that would like to assist others.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag function on every public cv page, in the lower right sidebar.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001306.html

Comment: Isn't this geared towards inappropriate content rather than fixing a detail for a user on a CV?